# Limitar texto en una tabla y crear saltos de linea

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

Intento crear una tabla con un espacio definido y entonces si uno de los componentes supera la capacidad de la tabla pasa esto:

[image: Img1]

Lo que me gustaría es que si pasa esto se generara un salto de linea pero no se como hacerlo. ¿Alguna ayudita?. Gracias de antemano.

```
<style>
    body, html {
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    #admin {
        height: 700px;
        background: rgb(60, 60, 60);
        color: white;
        width: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -350px;
        margin-left: -400px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        display: none;
    }

    #warn_n {
      font-size: 18px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 700px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #table_reason {
      width: 300px; 
    }

    #button_table {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    #warn_table {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 10px;
      left: 40%;
      margin-left: -100px;
      top: 20%;
      width: 560px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: white;
    }

    #list {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 640px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
                box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }

    .player {
        width: 100%;
        text-weight: bold;
        text-indent: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .player:nth-child(odd) {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, transparent 0%, rgb(85, 85, 85) 100%);
    }

    .player.selected {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, transparent 0%, rgb(126, 214, 218) 100%);
    }
</style>

<div id="warn_table">Table by JS</div>
```

Comment: podrias colocar tu html y css como lo tienes definido....

Comment: puedes fijarte que aqui lo hace bien: https://jsfiddle.net/rh4avc60/1/

Comment: agrega tu codigo para visualizar cual podria ser el problema